# Catch an error anywhere angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http

I'm working on an Angularjs app that frequently communicates with a server. I've been tasked with implementing security, when there wasn't any before.

This means that I've changed all the server side api calls to return a 403-unauthorized http status code when the user attempts to perform an action they aren't allowed to perform.

Now, I COULD go and hunt down every single API call that the app makes to the server, and call a function that handles the same error the same way in each one. But I would rather find some way to say "Any time this page gets a 403-unauthorized response, do this function." Is what I'm asking possible?

Comment: yes, you can use a $http Interceptor to intercept every http call and deal with your 403s there

Comment: @theTaoOfJS You should make that an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `$http` interceptors. By adding an interceptor, you will be able to intercept the response to check the status code and do whatever you want before the original requiring gets notified.

[Angularjs $http docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)

For example:

```
app.config(function ($httpProvider) {
  // it can be added by a explicit factory declaration
  // angular.module(...).factory('myHttpInterceptor', function ...
  $httpProvider.interceptors.push(function($q, $state) {
    return {
      'request': function(config) {
        return config;
      },

      'response': function(response) {
        if(response.statusCode === 403){
          $state.go('my.unauthorized.state');
          // or maybe 
          // $rootScope.$broadcast('unauthorized');
        }
        return response;
      }
    };
  });
});
```